# Trouble installing OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, codeblocks

I'm trying to use Opencv to capture video from a webcam.

I have the following code

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap;
}
```

Which causes the program to terminate with an error

> Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minutes, 34 seconds)

I'm wondering if I have not installed opencv correctly on codeblocks

Note that when I use this program instead, everything works fine

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY );
if ( !capture )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: capture is NULL \n" );
    getchar();
    return -1;
}

IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

cvNamedWindow( "mywindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

while ( 1 )
{
    frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
    if ( !frame )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: frame is null...\n" );
        getchar();
        break;
    }

    cvShowImage( "mywindow", frame );

    if ( (cvWaitKey(10) & 255) == 27 )
        break;
}

cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
cvDestroyWindow( "mywindow" );

return 0;
```

[image: linker Settings]
[image: compiler settings]
[image: linker]

**EDIT**

changing the headers to hpp files also produces the same problem

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I will note that the code blocks intelisense seems to know about VideoCapture. Compiling works ok, the problem is when I run the program.

Comment: Try with zeroth or negative device number as capture constructor argument.

Also, what did You expect to get from the firs version of the code? 

You did not return anything from the main function. Capture was created and then the program has reached it's end.

Comment: unfortunately adding the return value has not fixed the main problem. Also I have a webcam plugged in so device number one refers to my webcam.

Comment: Maybe try to surround Your function with a `try{...} catch(const cv::Exception &ex){std::cerr<<ex.what()<<std::endl}`? And try to find where the program terminates. Is it on creation of `cv::VideoCapture` or when You try to open it?

Comment: I tried the try catch statement, the program still crashes. I get the program has stopped working error message. No exception message is printed out. However when I comment out the VideoCapture cap(0) line there is no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program that compiles and runs uses OpenCV 1.x and the headers you included in the one that does not are from OpenCV 2.x. You need to install this version of OpenCV if you want it to work.

Comment: I got this version of Opencv relatively recently, it should have 2.x. 
do I need to use different headers?

Comment: @DwProd, they seem to be  version 2.4.2 from linked libraries

Comment: Yea it is, surely this version is fine to use? Have I used the wrong headers?

Comment: @sav, yes, you need to use C++ API headers with the extension ".hpp" if you want to use C++ libraries

Answer (score 1):

You need to include:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"  
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
```

instead of

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
```

C and C++ headers should not be included in the same OpenCV project. Finally, it should be like this:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"  
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, unfortunately I still have the same problem after trying this. "Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minutes, 8 seconds)
"

Comment: I may be wrong but it seems you have both versions installed. I suggest you get a clean install of the latest version of OpenCV 2.X, use the headers provided by thomas and use the proper libraries for linking.